# Using iterated writing in HDFS file by using Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am learning how to read and write from files in HDFS by using Spark/Scala.
I am unable to write in HDFS file, the file is created, but it's empty.
I don't know how to create a loop for writing in a file.

The code is:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

// Read the adult CSV file
  val logFile = "hdfs://zobbi01:9000/input/adult.csv"
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()


  //val logFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://zobbi01:9000/input/adult.csv")
  val headerAndRows = logData.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
  val header = headerAndRows.first
  val data = headerAndRows.filter(_(0) != header(0))
  val maps = data.map(splits => header.zip(splits).toMap)
  val result = maps.filter(map => map("AGE") != "23")

  result.foreach{

      result.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://zobbi01:9000/input/test2.txt")
  }
```

If I replace:
`result.foreach{println}`

Then it works!

but when using the method of (saveAsTextFile), then an error message is thrown as

```
<console>:76: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] => Unit
             result.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://zobbi01:9000/input/test2.txt")
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

```
result.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://zobbi01:9000/input/test2.txt")
```

This is all what you need to do. You don't need to loop through all the rows.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What this does!!!

```
 result.foreach{
  result.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://zobbi01:9000/input/test2.txt")
 }
```

RDD `action` cannot be triggered from RDD `transformations` unless special conf set.

Just use `result.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://zobbi01:9000/input/test2.txt")` to save to HDFS.

I f you need other formats in the file to be written, change in rdd itself before writing.

Comment: what's the difference than other answer?

Comment: Congrats!! Yu answered first!!! :) 

When I opened the tab, I dint see you answering. This anyway does not help the Question.

Comment: Many thanks. It works. It was my mistake when I actually saved to (test2.txt), thinking it was a file. Indeed, it is a folder so I changed to (test2)